# Error when placing legends

Tags: plotting, graphics, warning-messages, legending, error-tracking

Consider the following plot

```
plot = ListLinePlot[{{{0, 0}, {1, 1}}, {{0, 0}, {1, .8}}}, PlotLegends -> Placed[{"1", "2"}, {.8, .4}]]
```

[image]

When I try to apply `Image[plot]` I get the following error

[image]

If I remove the `Placed` option, however, this is fixed. Any idea how to fix this? I'm using Mathematica version 13.0.0.

Comment: `Image@Rasterize@plot`

Comment: or `Rasterize[plot, "Image"]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
p2 = ListLinePlot[{{{0, 0}, {1, 1}}, {{0, 0}, {1, .8}}}
  , Epilog -> 
   Inset[LineLegend[{ColorData[97][1], ColorData[97][2]}, {"1", 
      "2"}], {.8, .4}]
  ]

Head[%]

Image[p2]
```

---

**EDIT-1**  From the docs: `Inset[obj,pos]` is one of the available syntax. In response to the OP's comment, a manipulate is being added to show usage. As soon as `Placed` is used, the `Head` changes to `Legended`.

```
Manipulate[
 p3 = ListLinePlot[{
    {{0, 0}, {1, 1}}
    , {{0, 0}, {1, .8}}
    }
   , ImagePadding -> {{10, 10}, {10, 10}}
   , Epilog -> Inset[LineLegend[
      {ColorData[97][1]
       , ColorData[97][2]}
      , {"1", "2"}], {i, j}
     ]
   ],
 {{i, 0.5, "x", Appearance -> Labeled}, 0.1, 1.0}
 , {{j, 0.5, "y", Appearance -> Labeled}, 0.1, 1.0}
 ]
```

Comment: `Epilog` and `Inset` is a nice solution, but I wonder what the placement here means, what exactly are those units? With `Placed`, it was easy to see because the position corresponded to cartesian coordinates, here I'm not sure. Any idea?

Answer (score 3):

```
Rasterize[plot]
```

[image]

```
Head @ %
```

> ```
> Image
> ```

Comment: Is it possible to define the resolution of such image with `Rasterize`?

Comment: @samwolfe, you can play with the options [ImageResolution](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageResolution.html) and [RasterSize](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RasterSize.html) in `Rasterize`.

Answer (score 2):

Note that "plot" has a head of "Legended".

I do not know a straight way to change this into an image: However, a work around could be to save the plot as a PNG file and then importing as an image. However, the quality could be better.

```
Export["d:/tmp/test.png", plot]
img = Import["d:/tmp/test.png"]
```

[image]

Comment: Do you agree that I should add a bug tag?

Comment: @yode - I do not agree with a bug tag. The documentation for `Image` indicates that its argument should either be an array of data or a graphics. Since this `plot` does not have a `Head` of either `Graphics` or `Graphics3D`; it is not a valid input as indicated in the resulting error message.

Answer (score 1):

### Simple solution:

```
ImportString[ExportString[plot, "PNG"], "PNG"]
```

### Lossless solution:

```
Export["test.svg", plot]
img = ResourceFunction["SVGImport"]["test.svg"]
```